# inserted writes

Tags: c#, ado.net, insert, cycle

code :

```
SqlConnection sqlc = new SqlConnection(
                        "Data Source=" + Environment.MachineName + @"\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                        "Integrated security=true;" +
                        "database=someDB");

SqlCommand sqlcmd;
string tmp = string.Empty;

for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    tmp += "inserto into [db].[Files](...) values (...);"
}

sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(tmp, sqlc);
try { sqlc.Open(); sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuety(); } cathc{}
```

**inserted only < 1000 writes
How write all 100000 writes ?? May be destroy and create sqlcmd?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably split the commands up into smaller commands. Say, inserting 500 records per SqlCommand until you've inserted all your records.

```
int totalRecordsToWrite = 100000;
int maxRecordsPerCommand = 500;

SqlConnection sqlc = new SqlConnection(
                        "Data Source=" + Environment.MachineName + @"\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                        "Integrated security=true;" +
                        "database=someDB");

int currentRecord = 0;

while (currentRecord < totalRecordsToWrite)
{
    SqlCommand sqlcmd;
    string tmp = string.Empty;

    for(int j = 0; j < maxRecordsPerCommand; j++)
    {
        currentRecord++;

        if (currentRecord >= totalRecordsToWrite)
          break;

        // Insert record "currentRecord" of the 100000 here.

        tmp += "inserto into [db].[Files](...) values (...);"
    }

    using (sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(tmp, sqlc))
    {
       try { sqlc.Open(); sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuety(); } catch{}
    }
}
```

Comment: or a better way would be to optimize the sql to not have to do 100000 statements. perhaps a stored procedure also might be a better option?

Comment: and that as an argument to pass?

Comment: The above code is simply splitting up our queries into multiple smaller queries. How you use it depends on what your application does. Without further information, this is the best I can do :).

Comment: Updated answer with a dynamic total records and max records per command.